# SSL Client Certificate handshake using Square.SocketRocket.WebSocket for Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, websocket, xamarin.ios

Does anyone know if it is possible to pass a client certificate to the SocketRocket library ([square-bindings](https://github.com/mattleibow/square-bindings)).... basically a handshake..

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 'no'.
Turns out client certificate support has been removed. (deprecated)